# Why is 1 newton defined as 1 $\rm kg · m/s^2$?

Tags: forces, dimensional-analysis, si-units, metrology

From my limited understanding, one newton is defined as the amount of force that gives a mass of 1 kilogram an acceleration of 1 meter per second squared. What I don't understand is why it corresponds to the mathematical definition of a newton, namely N = 1 kg · m/s^2. Maybe my question extends further. If we think about equations such as these mathematically they have no meaning. What does it truly mean to multiply mass with acceleration or displacement divided by time? If I say 3 ÷ 5, to me it means that I multiply the number 3 with the multiplicative inverse of 5. But if I say displacement ÷ time then it makes no sense to me, because it would imply that there's such a thing as the multiplicative inverse of time, which to me makes little sense. Of course, I am thinking about this narrowly. Mass, acceleration, time, displacement, etc., are all quantities in physics and not numbers. I guess my question is, why have we chosen to define it like this mathematically and not in some other way? Why multiplication and not some other operation?

Comment: FWIW, the multiplicative inverse of time is a *rate*, or frequency - occurrences per unit time. The unit of hertz is exactly this, expressed as 1/s in SI units.

Comment: To accelerate a mass of one kg from zero to one m/s^2 you need one Newton, this is definition, long time ago the unit was Kp Kilopond the acceleration was 9.8 m/s^2 instead of 1 thus $N=kg\,\frac m{s^2}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't overthink it. There is nothing deep going on.

Because $F=m a$, the units of force need to be the units of mass times the units of acceleration. In SI units, we measure mass in ${\rm kg}$ and acceleration in ${\rm m}/{\rm s^2}$, so the SI unit of force must by ${\rm kg\ m}/{\rm s^2}$.

The reason we keep track of units is because we can always choose to *change* units. Suppose we decide to measure mass in pounds instead of kilograms, distances in feet instead of meters, and times in years instead of seconds. The numerical value of $ma$ will be different in these new units. To compensate, the numerical value of $F$ must also change, in such a way that the equation $F=ma$ remains true. The units we assign $F$ are chosen so that it is easy to keep track of how to do this conversion consistently.

Comment: So what I think you're saying is that we use multiplication in order to be able to change the units? That makes a lot of sense because we wouldn't be able to do that with other operators such as addition.

Comment: @OnionKing Yes. If you want to change from meters to feet, then you multiply all lengths by 3.28 feet/meter. In order to keep $F=ma$, you also need to multiple all forces by 3.28 feet/meter.

Comment: Thank you, this is very insightful!

Answer (score 2):

### Formal treatment

We can formally treat dimension units like mathematical variables, where we don't bother to find out their numerical value. E.g. we can treat a length of 3*m* as a product of the number 3 with a "variable" *m*.

If we do calculations with physical quantities, we can apply all the algebra rules on terms with variables to these calculations.

So, e.g. as we define

1 *N* = 1 *kg* · *m/s²*

this can be treated just like a mathematical equation *N* = *kg* · *m/s²*, thus introducing a new "variable" named *N*, and we know it to be the the "variable" *kg*, multiplied by *m*, divided by the square of *s*.

If we look at the equation on force, mass and acceleration

F = m · a

with values e.g.

m = 1000 *kg*

a = 2 *m/s²*

and simply substitute this into the equation, we get

F = 1000 *kg* · 2 *m/s²*

F = 2000 *kg m/s²*

And for the lengthy units term *kg m/s²*, with *N* = *kg* · *m/s²* (see above) we introduced a shorter name *N*, so we get

F = 2000 *N*

### Interpretation

Let me offer an interpretation supporting the treatment of physical units as mathematical variables, even though the underlying assumption is false.

Let's postulate a hypothetical world where everything is countable. (Although Quantum Physics supports some aspects of this premise, it is **not true**, but it **might help to get some grasp** on the concept of dimension units.)

Typically, we measure distances in meters. In our "countable" world, physics might at some time find out that the fundamental unit for distances is 1µm, that there are no smaller distances than that, and that all distances can be expressed as multiples of that fundamental unit.

We could express a 3*m* distance simply with the number 3000000. We could even write down an equation

3*m* = 3000000

which easily leads to *m*=1000000.

Of course, it won't be easy to find out the real fundamental distance unit, so the "value" of *m* will most probably stay unknown forever, but it doesn't matter as long as we always follow the algebra rules on calculations, meaning that we express all results as products of a numerical value and some units expression.

### Specific questions

> If we think about equations such as these mathematically they have no
> meaning.

See above, equations like 1 *N* = 1 *kg* · *m/s²* can be interpreted to introduce a new unit "variable" *N*, based on the pre-existing ones *kg*, *m*, and *s*. If we were ever able to quantify *kg*, *m*, and *s*, we'd be able to compute a value for *N* by evaluating the equation given above.

> Mass, acceleration, time, displacement, etc., are all quantities in
> physics and not numbers.

See above, they can indeed be understood as numbers, as products of a given numeric value with an unknown variable value called "unit".

> Why multiplication and not some other operation?

If we e.g. express the circumference of earth as 40000 *km*, it means that the circumference is 40000 times as long as a kilometer. We don't know how many "fundamental distance units" make up one kilometer, but to get the earth circumference, we have to multiply that number by 40000, so the correct expression is a multiplication 40000 · *km*, with *km* standing for the (unknown) number of fundamental distance units that fit into a kilometer.

Comment: Building off your answer, you could say that the point of dimensional analysis is that the equations of physics must satisfy the property that it is *impossible* to solve for a "numerical value" of base units like the kilogram, meter, and second, since the choice of units is arbitrary.

Comment: @Ralf Kleberhoff Your answer was very helpful!

Comment: @Andrew Very interesting insight!

Answer (score 0):

Doing *displacement over time* is another way of saying *split the displacement into unit-bits time*. If you move 10 metres in 5 seconds, then that corresponds to 2 metres moves for each second. We therefor invent a combo-unit called *metre/second* so that our mathematical writing stays consistent, even with units:

$$\frac{\text{displacement}}{\text{time}}=\frac{10\,\mathrm{m}}{5\,\mathrm{s}}=2 5\,\mathrm{m/s}.$$

Physically, we invent a name for this new compo-property and call it (average) **speed**. The belonging combo-unit is then simplye **metres-per-second** because it makes the notation fit. (When I say "combo-property" and "combo-unit" I actually mean *derived property* and *derived unit*.)

So, whenever you see, in physical contexts and physics' use of mathematics, a combo-unit then simply read it out loud. *That* is the meaning it has been invented and defined to have. $\mathrm{m/s}$ is "metres per second" or in long version "a number of metres moved in one second" (if the speed were constant).

Regarding the unit of force, it is defined - derived - directly from the definition, which is Newton's 2nd law:

$$F=ma.$$

$F$ is defined as the effort it takes to accelerate some amount of mass with acceleration $a$. In SI units: the effort requires to accelerate some number of kilograms with a specific metres-per-second-per-second. This unit bundle, $\mathrm{kg\cdot m/s^2}$, is then given a name: The Newton, $\mathrm N$.

Comment: If I understand correctly then what you're saying is that m/s is its own unit and isn't a composition of two different units?

Comment: @OnionKing It is both. It is a new unit in itself derived from the two fundamental units which it then consists of. It is a "unit bundle" that we treat as a unit in itself for the derived property.

Comment: Should this not be average **velocity** rather than average **speed**?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero If we are talking about the displacement as a vector over time, then yes. If we are talking about just the displacement magnitude over time, then no need. They are equivalent ways of expressing the relationship

Answer (score 0):

Newton's law tells you that
$$
F=ma \quad \Rightarrow \quad \text{Force unit} = \text{mass unit} \times \text{acc. unit}
$$
If you are using the [mks system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MKS_system_of_units#:%7E:text=The%20MKS%20system%20of%20units,redefined%20by%20different%20fundamental%20constants.) (meter, kg, second), then the mks unit for the force is

"Force unit in mks system"$=kg (m/s^2)$.

Then, this unit is called "Newton" to honour the guy that wrote $F=ma$.

PS: try to follow the same reasoning for the [cgs system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centimetre%E2%80%93gram%E2%80%93second_system_of_units). You should find the [Dyne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyne).